# error: cannot find symbol in gradle compileTestJava

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting lots of `error: cannot find symbol` errors when the compileTestJava task runs in my Gradle project.

My code is in `src/main/java` and my tests are in `src/test/java` and the test classes cannot resolve any classes in `src/main/java`

e.g.:

```
C:\q\src\test\java\q\MainTest.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            Main.main(new String[0]);
            ^
  symbol:   variable Main
  location: class MainTest
```

But `q\src\main\java\q\Main.java` exists, compiles and is a public class in the same package.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}
```

I have been working around this by adding the following to build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
       test {
               java.srcDirs = ['src/main/', 'src/test/']
       }
}
```

And that works, but it causes errors in IntelliJ.

Comment: Your solution works for me too; but it doesn't make sense to me that we weren't having any issues until just today, and I don't know of anything we changed as to why this wasn't necessary before.

Comment: @MuffinTheMan I've done a bit more work but am still continuing my investigations - I've tried updating Gradle but that didn't work, however copying my src/ directory into a newly inited Gradle project fixed the problem. I was going to try deleting my ~/.gradle directory to see if that helped but haven't had time to try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the same fix did work.

I also managed to make it work without the fix. In my case, the issue was caused by the path of the project. It was nested inside a directory that had colons (`:`) in its name. Maybe look for any other irregularities (semicolons, spaces, ...) also.